# How to mix different type of assert in Data Driven test in MSTest

Tags: c#, .net, mstest

I'd like to write test for a function in MSTest, this function has different output, normally it will return an int value when correctly complete, but it will also throw different type of exception if input is invalid, null or out of range.

For normal output I use Assert.AreEqual(), and for exception I use Assert.ThrowsException<ExceptionType>().  Is there any way to combine them together in one DynamicData Data Driven test?

Thank you.

Here is the test code I use, all test cases and expected results are written in code.  I'm wondering if it's possible to use Dynamic Data Driven to sperate test case from test code, and execute all test case in one test method.

```
            var approval = CreateSendToApproverTestCase();
            approval.SignTicketId = signTicketId;
            approval.AssignedTo = "alice ; ";

            var newApproval = _approvalService.CreateApproval(approval);
            currentApproverId = newApproval.SignTicketApprovalId;
            Assert.IsTrue(currentApproverId.ToLong() > 0);
            Thread.Sleep(3000);

            approval.AssignedTo = "alice ; aabbb ";
            Assert.ThrowsException<UserNotExistException>(() => _approvalService.CreateApproval(approval, false));

            approval.AssignedTo = "";
            Assert.ThrowsException<NullUserException>(() => _approvalService.CreateApproval(approval, false));

            approval.AssignedTo = "alice";
            approval.Buttons[0].Text = "__Cancel";
            Assert.ThrowsException<ButtonTextException>(() => _approvalService.CreateApproval(approval, false));
```

Comment: can you please give a clearer explanation of "combine them together"? Maybe an example of what you want?

Comment: You have different behavior to expect from the method based on the test data. That is better not combined in one test method. You should have two test methods one which asserts the output of the method and the on the other one which asserts the exception.